# Checkboxes generated via CheckBoxFor helper turn into type=hidden because of MaterializeCSS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, materialize, checkboxfor

I'm creating a website with ASP.NET MVC5 and I'm using [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/) for the first time, which looks like a very exciting framework.

However, the checkboxes generated by CheckBoxFor helper become hidden !
When I write :

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsAgreeTerms)
```

The generated HTML is :

```
<input name="IsAgreeTerms" type="hidden" value="false">
```

Why does Materialize change my `type=checkbox` into `type=hidden` ?
I tried to add `type="checkbox"` in the CheckboxFor helper, but it doesnt change anything. The only way is to modify in in my browser's console.

The only solution I found is [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094318/how-to-get-materializecss-checkbox-to-work-with-html-checkboxfor).
However, the accepted answer doesn't change anything for me.
The other answer works, but I think it's ugly to add some JS script to modify what Materialize modifies without my consent.

Is there any way to say "Hey, I ask for a `type=checkbox`, so just let my `type=checkbox` in the generated HTML" ?

Thank you

**UPDATE** :
My full ASP.NET MVC code is :

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsAgreeTerms, new { @type = "checkbox" })
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsAgreeTerms, new { @class = "login-label" })
```

The full generated HTML is

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="Le champ IsAgreeTerms est requis." id="IsAgreeTerms" name="IsAgreeTerms" type="checkbox" value="true"
<input name="IsAgreeTerms" type="hidden" value="false">
<label class="login-label" for="IsAgreeTerms">IsAgreeTerms</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in the form of a html helper. It constructs a checkbox and label in the correct order:

```
public static IHtmlString CheckBoxWithLabelFor<TModel>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression,
        string labelText,
        object htmlAttributes = null
    )
{
    if (expression == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));
    }

    var checkBoxWithHidden = htmlHelper.CheckBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes).ToHtmlString().Trim();
    var pureCheckBox = checkBoxWithHidden.Substring(0, checkBoxWithHidden.IndexOf("<input", 1, StringComparison.Ordinal));
    var labelHtml = htmlHelper.LabelFor(expression, labelText).ToHtmlString().Trim();
    var result = pureCheckBox + Environment.NewLine + labelHtml + Environment.NewLine + $"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"{ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)}\" value=\"false\" />";

    return new MvcHtmlString(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there other html generated by materialize.css? I think this happens because it is not possible apply a custom CSS to element input of type checkbox.

So, the checkbox becomes hidden and other html component represents visually the checkbox.  Many components work like that.

**UPDATE:**
[Why is Html checkbox generating an additional hidden input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697299/asp-net-mvc-why-is-html-checkbox-generating-an-additional-hidden-input)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question. I'm not a CSS specialist but he main problem here is that all my checkboxes generated by Razor became hidden. Even if I don't want to style them...
Here, if I manually change `type="hidden"` by `type="checkbox"` in the 2nd generated input in my browser's console, it's perfectly working.

Comment: Ok. I got it. Here, is the best answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697299/asp-net-mvc-why-is-html-checkbox-generating-an-additional-hidden-input

Answer (score 0):

OP here. Problem looks like more complex.

Actually, when using `@Html.CheckBoxFor`, MVC5 generates 3 fields, in that order :

- Your input, with `type="checkbox"`, binded to your model property
- An hidden field (see the Claudio's link for an explaination)
- Your label, generated by `@Html.LabelFor`

Problem is `Materialize` expects that in another order to work.
In your browser's console, just move the `<label>` element between the input and the hidden field, and everything works fine !

I found [this very useful link](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2994), where, basically, it is said that the order of the generated fields by `@Html.checkBoxFor` will change ... In MVC6 !

As I'm working with MVC5, I use this **very ugly** solution in my `_Layout`:

```
$(":checkbox").each(function () {
    $(this).nextAll("label").before($(this))
})
```

#### If anyone has a better idea, please feel free to post an elegant solution.